# Как сформировать java классы из WSDL(+included XSD) c помощью maven-jaxb2-plugin?

Tags: maven, xsd, wsdl, jaxb

Пытаюсь разобраться с  WSDL SOAP XSD. В общем как генерить классы с помощью плагина разобрался, но если WSDL берется по ссылке.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.13.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                    <generatePackage>hello.wsdl</generatePackage>
                    <schemas>
                        <schema><url>http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL</url>
                        </schema>
                    </schemas>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

но как сделать тоже самое если WSDL лежит в файле в ресурсах?

```
resources/wsdl/my.wsdl
```

И еще имеет в себе зависимости на XSD но хотябы просто без зависимостей, как сгенерить из этого классы? нашел разные варианты типо этого

```
<configuration>
                <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                <generatePackage>hello.wsdl</generatePackage>
                <schemaDirectory>resources/wsdl/my.wsdl</schemaDirectory>
            </configuration>
```

не работает. Искал в документации нашел [это](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Specifying-What-To-Compile)

Перепробовал все варианты не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

**Дисклеймер:** я автор [maven-jaxb2-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-jaxb2-plugin).

Если `my.wsdl` лежит в `src/main/resources`, то проще всего:

```
<configuration>
    <schemaIncludes><include>*.wsdl</include></schemaIncludes>
</configuration>
```

Я не рекомендую, правда, WSDL при помощи [maven-jaxb2-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-jaxb2-plugin) обрабатывать. Пользуйтесь лучше CXF.